# How do I report January 2021 wash sales in the 2020 tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, wash-sale

****Do I need to report my January 2021 wash sales in my 2020 tax return or how are they handled?**** I have some wash sales in the month of January which are of course the result of similar transactions that took place in Dec 2020. I am not sure what should be done with them. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but you don't have to explicitly declare a wash sale. It's just something that affects your cost basis for when it comes time to compute the capital gain/loss resulting from a sale.

Comment: @chepner - Brokers report wash sales to the IRS on Form 8949.  A wash sale isn't always a single clean event.  Scaling in and out of positions can lead to a portion of the loss being deductible and a portion of the loss having to be carried forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you realized losses in December of 2020 and your transactions in January of 2021 triggered a wash sale then some/all of your 2020 loss will have to be carried forward (the trigger is replacement shares < 31 days after the 2020 realized loss).

If you were out of a 2020 position for 30 days then there is no 2020 wash sale problem and your 2021 wash sales belong to 2021.

Answer (score 0):

*Sales* in a given year are what your capital gains taxes care about. For whichever year the actual sale occurred, the reduction or elimination of the loss is reflected on your Schedule D. The corresponding increase in basis (of the replacement shares you bought) is not noted in your taxes until you sell some or all of the replacement shares, when it will lead to a reduced gain or increased loss on that year's Schedule D.

Note that a wash sale can involve replacement shares purchased either before or after the sale, so there are various permutations for timing of the wash sale and the sale of replacement shares.